# Boost Graph Library: Check validity of vertex_descriptor in a performant way

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

The BGL aims to be as generic as possible. Therefore I have written for an interface for another piece of software that also aims to be as generic as possible. However, I get problems, when the vertex_descriptor is not valid.

Here is a minimal example that describes the problem:

```cpp
template <class Graph>
class Wrapper {
  public:
    T& get_property_obj(const typename Graph::vertex_descriptor& v) {
        // This should be inserted:
        // if (invalid_descriptor(v)) {
        //    throw something;
        // }
        return g[v];
    }
  private:
    Graph& g;
};
```

The problem is that when `Graph` is a `boost::adjacency_list` with `vecT` as vertex storage type the `Graph::operator[` does not seem to check if `v` is valid and can deliver invalid memory.

Can I somehow do a simple check in the wrapper class that `v` is valid?

Obviously the simplest solution is to iterate over all vertices and check for equality but for the given example a check of `vertex_descriptor` and `num_vertices()` would be sufficient (but of course not generic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell whether a vertex descriptor is *valid*.

You can only check

- the range (in case of integral vertex descriptors, like with vecS)
- by looking it up for node-based vertex storage descriptors.

However, both scenarios risk giving you the wrong results, for the same reason that standard library containers do:

```
 std::vector<int> is{1,2,3};
 auto i1 = is.begin();

 is.push_back(4);

 std::cout << "Undefined Behaviour: " << *i1;
```

The point is, the iterator (or descriptor as the case may be) has been invalidated. There's no way to detect this happened¹, you'll always have to deal with it yourself.

The iterator/descriptor invalidation guarantees follow the guarantees of the underlying containers though. This means that for node-based containers, you can actually rely on descriptors (and references) being stable across insertion and even deletion (*except* for the element that was deleted, obviously).

See e.g. [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

So for integral descriptors, you'd write:

```
bool descriptor_looks_valid(vertex_descriptor v) const {
    return v>=0 && v < num_vertices(g);
}
```

As you know, it'll be horribly inefficient for most other container selectors:

```
bool descriptor_looks_valid(vertex_descriptor v) const {
    auto vds = vertices(g);
    return std::count(vds.first, vds.second, v);
}
```

Or generically (assuming c++17):

```
bool descriptor_looks_valid(vertex_descriptor v) const {
    if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<vertex_descriptor>) {
        return v>=0 && v < num_vertices(g);
    } else {
        auto vds = vertices(g);
        return std::count(vds.first, vds.second, v);
    }
}
```

### Demonstration Of The Perils

This tiny demo shows the perils of mistaking "range check pass" for "valid". This program repeats this:

```
template <typename vertexS> void doTest() {
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS,
        vertexS,
        boost::directedS,
        PropertyObj>;

    Graph g;
    auto v1 = add_vertex({"one"}, g);
    auto v2 = add_vertex({"two"}, g);
    auto v3 = add_vertex({"three"}, g);
    auto v4 = add_vertex({"four"}, g);
    auto v5 = add_vertex({"five"}, g);

    Wrapper w = g;
    std::cout << w.get_property_obj(v3).something << std::endl;

    // but this is confounding, and only accidentally "works" for vecS:
    remove_vertex(v1, g);
    std::cout << w.get_property_obj(v3).something << std::endl;

    try {
        // this looks "valid" with vecS, but should throw for listS
        //
        // of course, like with v3 the descriptor was already invalidated both cases
        std::cout << w.get_property_obj(v1).something << std::endl;
    } catch(std::range_error const& re) {
        std::cout << "(range_error cautgh: " << re.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

For `vertexS` equal to `vecS`, `listS` or `setS`. Typical  output is **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/891fa227d80bfdad)</kbd>**:

```
Testing with vecS:
three
four
two

Testing with listS:
three
three
(range_error caught: get_property_obj

Testing with setS:
three
three
(range_error caught: get_property_obj
```

### Conclusion

The reason validity checks aren't implemented is because the underlying containers do not support them.

Also, although you can "approximate" a validation this will only prevent against crashes, not against unspecified behavior.

In fact, depending on what semantics are expected you might trigger [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) just the same (e.g. if you assume that `get_property_obj(v3)` yields the same value each time, you will have broken code with `vecS`).

> Can I somehow do a simple check in the wrapper class that v is valid?

In short, no.Descriptor validity is a function of the usage patterns and the caller will have to account for it.

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/891fa227d80bfdad)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct PropertyObj {
    std::string something;
};

template <class Graph, class T = PropertyObj>
class Wrapper {
  public:
    using vertex_descriptor = typename Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    T& get_property_obj(vertex_descriptor v) {
        if (!descriptor_looks_valid(v)) 
            throw std::range_error("get_property_obj");
        return g[v];
    }
    Wrapper(Graph& g) : g(g){}
  private:
    bool descriptor_looks_valid(vertex_descriptor v) const {
        if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<vertex_descriptor>) {
            return v>=0 && v < num_vertices(g);
        } else {
            auto vds = vertices(g);
            return std::count(vds.first, vds.second, v);
        }
    }

    Graph& g;
};

template <typename vertexS> void doTest() {
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS,
        vertexS,
        boost::directedS,
        PropertyObj>;

    Graph g;
    auto v1 = add_vertex({"one"}, g);
    auto v2 = add_vertex({"two"}, g);
    auto v3 = add_vertex({"three"}, g);
    auto v4 = add_vertex({"four"}, g);
    auto v5 = add_vertex({"five"}, g);

    boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning(v1);
    boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning(v2);
    boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning(v3);
    boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning(v4);
    boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning(v5);

    Wrapper w = g;
    std::cout << w.get_property_obj(v3).something << std::endl;

    // but this is confounding, and only accidentally "works" for vecS:
    remove_vertex(v1, g);
    std::cout << w.get_property_obj(v3).something << std::endl;

    try {
        // this looks "valid" with vecS, but should throw for listS
        //
        // of course, like with v3 the descriptor was already invalidated both cases
        std::cout << w.get_property_obj(v1).something << std::endl;
    } catch(std::range_error const& re) {
        std::cout << "(range_error caught: " << re.what() << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Testing with vecS:\n";
    doTest<boost::vecS>();

    std::cout << "\nTesting with listS:\n";
    doTest<boost::listS>();

    std::cout << "\nTesting with setS:\n";
    doTest<boost::setS>();
}
```

---

¹ although some library implementations have extensions that allow you to detect it some of the time - like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/debug-iterator-support?view=vs-2019

Comment: Note: the use of `std::count` is for brevity and not as efficient as it can be